# Problematic code completion of tailwindcss in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I would like to use `nuxtjs` together with `tailwindcss` for my frontend project. I have integrated `tailwindcss` via module like this:

```
  buildModules: [
    // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/nuxt-tailwindcss
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss'
  ],
```

The `tailwindcss` works now, but the code completion does not. There are two Intellij IDEA plugins which indeed do add a code completion for tailwind - but when I start to customize the `tailwind.config.js` file they fail, because they only suggest classes based on the default tailwind configuration (they don't recognize my own classes AND they suggest classes which are not available anymore because I have removed them via config file).

I could make a very similar setup work with react's `nextjs` - because this framework created an output css file in the `.next` folder, and IDEA could pick up on that. This then inspired me so I tried to remove the `@nuxtjs/tailwindcss` module, and set up the `tailwindcss` manually via `postcss` build option in `nuxt`. No file was created in the `.nuxt` folder, not even when I added the `extractCSS: true` option there.

I would like to achieve the result from `nextjs` in `nuxtjs` too. Does anyone have an elegant solution for that?

PS: I would like to stay with IDEA, and I would like to avoid manually creating tailwind output via console somewhere in my project everytime my tailwind configuration changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To this day I have not found a perfect answer to this. **The solution I use is the one that generates the tailwind styles inside a hidden (git ignored) folder**. That allows IDEA to pick up on the styles correctly. The only disadvantage is that you have to re-build the styles if you change configuration (which almost never happens besides the very start of the project).

So having the tailwind setup inside `assets/css/tailwind.css`, I will have a script like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "tailwind": "npx tailwindcss build assets/css/tailwind.css -o .tailwind/tailwind.css"
},
```

The IDEA will then be able to pick up classes from `.tailwind/tailwind.css` directory.

Comment: Simple and easy answer, you saved me a lot of time. Thank you.

Comment: @ThanosParavantis thanks! maybe it's not the most up-to-date though. At least the WebStorm got a pretty good tailwind code completion by now. Check it out for IDEA and let me know, maybe it's worth updating the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try do npm install -D tailwindcss@latest in same probject.

for here "webstorm/IntelliJ IDEA" first detect "tailwind css" when "tailwind css" are as dependencies in package.json - plugin not understand nuxt-tailwindcss :D

Comment: Did this work for you or have you tried it?

Comment: Webstorm got a good tailwindcss support in the meantime so the code completion works without any hacks really well now. I didn't try it in IDEA :-D

Comment: this doesn't work for me.